What closed curves $γ$ make $\int_γ (\frac {7} {z − 2}+\frac {11} {z − 3})dz = 6πi$?
The following problem makes me a little confused as it doesn't resemble anything I've seen before:
Let $f(z) = \frac {7}
 {z − 2}+\frac {11} {z − 3}.$   Determine a closed curve $γ$ such that $\int_γ
 f(z)dz = 6πi.$  (It's
ok to draw the curve.  No explicit parameterization is needed.)
It seems like the curve doesn't have to be simple, so maybe we can let it wind once around the point $z=3$ clockwise and twice around the point $z=2$ counterclockwise. If we do, the value of the integral becomes $3×2\pi i=6\pi i$ as desired, I think, since $(-1)×11+2×7=3$
But that would be a weirdly looking curve with a lot of intersections. What theorems could we rely on to make sure that the value of the integral is really what we want it to be? So far I've encountered only curves with a much less complicated appearance.

Yes, the curve will have to intersect itself. This isn't an issue, you can arrange for there to only be finitely many intersections. Then you can break the curve up into pieces based on these intersections to reduce to the simple case if you want.

I see, good! Is the curve allowed to go along its own footprints when it has made the first lap around one of the points?

It can, but if that makes you uncomfortable you can just shift it a little bit. Homotopy invariance of the contour integral lets you be very floppy with the shapes of contours.

Shifting it a bit would actually make me feel more uncomfortable as I don't know how to evaluate integrals along curves with weird shapes. If a curve is a circle or a repeated circle, then I view it as familiar.

Have you gotten to the residue theorem?

Yes, I'm familiar with that result.

Cool, well the good news is, it doesn't require the curve to be a circle!

That's nice, but so far I've seen the residue theorem being applied only to problems involving simple closed curves. The existence of intersections and repetitions makes me uncomfortable.

Ah, you're working with a reference that hasn't stated the version with winding numbers?

Yes, I know nothing about winding numbers or intersecting curves

I see, then I think @QiaochuYuan's first comment is your best bet: arrange the curve in such a way that you can reduce to the simple case, for which you do have a theorem at hand.

Ok. The only way to reduce the problem to cases that I'm familiar with is to make the curve go along its own footprints after the first lap.

Yuan and rafik disagree on whether the curve has to intersect itself or not.
