Is Cauchy's integral theorem valid also for complex closed curves or only for simple ones?
I've been viewing Cauchy's integral theorem as a statement about complex line integrals of holomorphic functions along simple closed curves, but recently I asked myself what happens if a curve winds several times around a point, has a lot of self intersections, and therefore is not simple.
I'm assuming, as is normally done, that the curve lies entirely within a simply connected domain where the function is holomorphic, but my assumptions about the curve are weakened in the way that I've explained.
Maybe the deformation invariance theorem suggests that the value of the integral is still zero, but it could be the case that we are allowed to deform a curve only within certain limits. Exaggerated deformations resulting in numerous self intersections or other abnormalities could be prohibited.
What's the right way to think about this?

Cauchy's integral theorem is true for arbitrary smooth curves, which can wind and self-intersect many times. I don't know what the easiest way is to prove this from scratch is but abstractly it follows from the fact that the contour integral $\oint_C f(z) , dz$ only depends on the homology class $[C] \in H_1$ (which is the strongest possible version of deformation invariance).

If there are finitely many self-intersections you can, as we discussed previously (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4951036/what-closed-curves-%ce%b3-make-int-%ce%b3-frac-7-z-%e2%88%92-2-frac-11-z-%e2%88%92-3dz-6), cut the curve up at each of these self-intersections and reduce to the simple case. But things are actually still fine even if there are infinitely many self-intersections.

Ok. Could we alternatively use the fact that a function which is holomorphic in a simply connected domain has an antiderivative there, and then apply the fundamental theorem of calculus? But I'm not sure what restrictions we need to put on a curve for the fundamental theorem of calculus to hold.

The FTC is valid for arbitrary smooth curves.

Even for curves with self intersections and with weird winding behaviours?

Yes, that doesn't enter into the proof at all. You just take derivatives! It does not matter in the slightest whether there are self-intersections! Windings also do not matter because you assumed $U$ was simply connected.

Okay, here's an alternative argument. If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a simply connected open domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, then (by Cauchy's integral theorem!) it has a global antiderivative on $U$, namely
$$F(z) = \oint_{\gamma : z_0 \to z} f(w) \, dw$$
where $\gamma : [0, 1] \to U$ is a smooth curve from $z_0$ to $z$, whatever type of curve you proved Cauchy's theorem holds for (which implies that $F(z)$ does not depend on the choice of $\gamma$). The argument that $F(z)$ is an antiderivative is given on Wikipedia. It follows that if $\gamma$ is any smooth curve, not necessarily closed, then by the FTC for contour integrals
$$\oint_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = F(\gamma(1)) - F(\gamma(0))$$
so $\oint_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = 0$ for any smooth closed curve $\gamma$, not necessarily simple.
The following is an abstract comment and can be safely ignored:

 Abstractly, I may not be familiar with the details of how to make sure any particular version of this argument is airtight, but I am deeply not worried about the possibility that any particular version of this statement could actually be false. This is because the strongest version of deformation invariance of contour integrals follows from the strongest version of Stokes' theorem; this generalizes the Green's theorem proof of Cauchy's integral theorem, and implies that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on an arbitrary open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, then the value of the contour integral $\oint_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz$ for a smooth closed curve $\gamma$ only depends on the homology class of the contour $[\gamma]$ in $H_1(U, \mathbb{Z})$. Roughly speaking, in this context taking homology boils down to keeping track of all the relations between contour integrals which are implied by homotopy invariance + the fact that stitching two contours together adds their contour integrals, and the homology class $[\gamma]$ ends up being an abstract summary of the winding numbers of $\gamma$ around all the holes in $U$, at least for "reasonable" $U$. If $U$ is simply connected then $H_1(U, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ so it follows that $\oint_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = 0$, and for "reasonable" $U$ (e.g. an open disk minus finitely many points) we get an expression in terms of a sum over winding numbers and residues; that is, we get the residue theorem.


I doubt your first alternative argument is valid (but ok you did address it in the comment), because at some stage we have to invoke simply-connectedness and so we need to use a result about homotopy-invariance of the integral, and I don’t see how this follows from Cauchy’s theorem alone. Also, Wikipedia glosses over this issue by proving only that “$\int_{\gamma}f(z),dz=0$ for all $\gamma$ implies $f$ has an antiderivative”, but they only mention without proof that the premise holds when the domain is simply-connected or star-shaped.

But anyway, for OP: if interested, a suitably general version (along the lines of the hidden comment, but not quite using the language of homology) can be found in Henri Cartan’s complex analysis text.

@peek-a-boo: sorry, which argument are you referring to? The one in my first comment or the one in this answer?

my first comment is about your first paragraph in this answer, and even ensuring that under the assumption of simply-connectedness, $F(z)=\int_{\gamma:z_0\to z}f(w),dw$ is even well-defined. Wikipedia doesn’t prove this (and I’m saying I don’t see how this follows from Cauchy’s theorem alone). It essentially assumes it is well-defined, and proves $F$ is an antiderivative.

@peek-a-boo: the argument I had in mind is the following: suppose you've proven Cauchy's theorem in the form $\oint_{\gamma} f(z) , dz = 0$ for $f$ holomorphic on a simply connected open $U$ and $\gamma$ a closed curve in some reasonable class of curves; we need this class of curves to have the property that 1) every pair of points is connected by some curve in this class, and 2) this class of curves is closed under concatenation. Then we can define $F(z)$ and its value is independent of the choice of $\gamma$, because given two curves $\gamma, \gamma'$ we can apply Cauchy's theorem...

...to the closed curve given by concatenating $\gamma$ and the reverse of $\gamma$' (so I also need the reasonable class of curves to be closed under reversal). Now, if the OP only believes Cauchy's theorem for simple curves then we need to work a little harder, since this class of curves is not closed under concatenation. In that case we need to use homotopy invariance to deform $\gamma'$ until it doesn't intersect $\gamma$. Is there an issue with this?

Yes, I thought that path independence, which makes the given integral well defined, follows from Cauchy's integral theorem alone, since you get a closed curve if you glue two different paths from one point to another together.

hmm ok I think that works, but it seems like we need to be careful in the deformation process as you mentioned, and give that a separate argument as well (I’m sure it’s doable, but writing it out formally seems more work than proving from the beginning a sufficiently general version of Cauchy’s theorem as in your hidden comment)

Yes, I've started wondering how much we are allowed to deform a curve. That's why I posted my question. But if I understand Yuan correctly, we are allowed to make weird deformations resulting in self intersections and other abnormalities.

Yes, maybe the deformation process is the hardest part of the argument, depending on which version of Cauchy's integral theorem we start with. @A A: yes, homotopy invariance of the contour integral (for functions holomorphic on $U$) holds for an arbitrary smooth homotopy between two smooth curves (in $U$); the curves can have many self-intersections and so can the homotopy.
